# I have an error while running jobs with GItLab CI/CD kubernetes executor within the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, rbac

ERROR: Job failed (system failure): pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:gitlab:gitlab-admin" cannot create resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "gitlab"

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it, because you did not provided enough information I would say that your [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) is incorrectly configure.
I would advice to read following Kubernetes documentation regarding [Managing Service Accounts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/) and [Configure Service Accounts for Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/).

If I'm not mistaken this command should fix it:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding gitlab-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --group=system:serviceaccounts --namespace=gitlab
```

If not then you will need to edit your [Role and ClusterRole](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) with something like the following:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: gitlab
  name: gitlab-admin
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["create", "get", "watch", "list"]
```

This is an example and you should make changes to better suit your needs.

If you provide more details I'll try to help you further.